# Assign a unique number to every unique product number in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets. *Sheet1* has a list of products and *Sheet2* has a list of products and their location. Since the product can be in multiple locations, there are a good amount of duplicates in *Sheet2*.

There are 26,000 products. I have assigned each product a number in *Sheet1*, 1-26,000. Is there a way for me to assign each number to the correct product in *Sheet2*?

This is a example of what I need:

[image]

The top table would be *Sheet1* and the bottom table would be *Sheet2*, the one with duplicates.
This is what they look like right now:

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

Please let me know if I did not explain this well enough. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You tagged this [tag:excel-vba]. Are you looking for a VBA solution or you just thought that that is maybe the best way. If so, you need to include what you've tried and the issues you want to solve. Be specific about it. Btw, I fixed your post but it seems that *Sheet1* and *Sheet2* screen shot were interchanged. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I tagged it with that to see if anyone knew of a solution using VB. Although I don't know much about VB and haven't tried anything with it yet =/ Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy your column A in sheet 1 to column c

Then in your sheet 2 column C row 2, use =vlookup(B2,'sheet1'!B:C,2,0) 
(if your first item is in B2)

Drag your formula down and it should work.

Comment: Since Sheet2 is actually in a different file I changed it to this: =VLOOKUP(B2,count.txt!$B:$C,2,0) but it didn't work. It says N/A. Thank you! EDIT: Please take a look at the screenshots I posted above.

Comment: Had to make my Import Set No column C, but it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use VLOOKUP or the INDEX MATCH combo formulas in the second sheet to locate the ITEM IDs in the first worksheet

Answer (score 0):

If you're *Item ID's* are sorted the way you illustrate it, then you can simply use an *IF* formula:
For example you have a data as shown:

[image]

Enter this formula in A2:

`=IF(B2=B1,IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,1),IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1+1,1))`

Above formula will give you what you've described.
Again, your items should be sorted so that same *Item ID* are in order.